# UnionAll for dataframes with different columns from list in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a List of dataframes: val dfs= Seq[df1,df2,df3,df4,....]

df1:

```
+--------+--------+
| value1 | Amount |
+--------+--------+
| A      | 300    |
+--------+--------+
| B      | 400    |
+--------+--------+
| C      | 200    |
+--------+--------+
```

df2

```
+--------+--------+
| Value1 | Amount |  
+--------+--------+
| A1     | 2000   |  
+--------+--------+
| B1     | 100    |  
+--------+--------+
| C1     | 349    |  
+--------+--------+
```

df3:

```
+--------+--------+
| value1 | Amount |
+--------+--------+
| A2     | 20     |
+--------+--------+
| B2     | 34     |
+--------+--------+
| C2     | 56     |
+--------+--------+
```

df4:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| value1 | value2 | amount |
+--------+--------+--------+
| A3     | CA     | 234    |
+--------+--------+--------+
| B3     | AZ     | 324    |
+--------+--------+--------+
| C3     | NY     | 213    |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to union all the dataframes in list, but due to difference in number of columns, unable to do it.
For unionAll: when I do unionall 
dfs.reduce(*unionall*).show()

Instead of unionall first three dataframes , adding fourth column as null and perform the unionall with df4. Can someone help me how to do , unionall in generic way., taking the dataframes from list

how to do unionAll operation in loop condition for list of dataframes with different columns?

Expected output:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| value1 | value2 | amount |
+--------+--------+--------+
| A      | null   | 300    |
+--------+--------+--------+
| B      | null   | 400    |
+--------+--------+--------+
| C      | null   | 200    |
+--------+--------+--------+
| A1     | null   | 2000   |
+--------+--------+--------+
| B1     | null   | 100    |
+--------+--------+--------+
| C1     | null   | 349    |
+--------+--------+--------+
| A2     | null   | 20     |
+--------+--------+--------+
| B2     | null   | 34     |
+--------+--------+--------+
| C2     | null   | 56     |
+--------+--------+--------+
| A3     | CA     | 234    |
+--------+--------+--------+
| B3     | AZ     | 324    |
+--------+--------+--------+
| C3     | NY     | 213    |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: @SergeyKhudyakov can you tell me how to create the udf(expr) for this type of scenario.

Comment: This is already explained in the answer of the link - what's wrong with it? You should really try to understand the code there